# Can't import react big calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Im trying to import the component 'react-big-calendar':

```
import React from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';`
```

> could not find a declaration file for module react big calendar

Iv'e already tried to use the npm @Types.. but it didnt work

Comment: It actually looks ok. Did you forget "npm install react-big-calendar"?

Comment: I did it sir, ive got errors in the installation though suchs as:
 Not found: @types/react-big-calendar@latest
Not found: react-big latest@

Comment: And if  you try to specify the exact version: `npm install react-big-calendar@0.20.2`?

Comment: still, something very strange here, i saw many people in another forum have the same problem, but no soultion suggested

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if they fixed this problem on later versions but I had a similar problem when trying to import it on a Next project using TypeScript.

I was able to solve it by running `npm install --save @types/react-big-calendar`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no BigCalendar component being exported from the 'react-big-calendar. I've checked the files and found no export for this component.

You can import the Calendar component from react-big-calendar library though and rename it to BigCalendar if you want as follows:

```
import {Calendar as BigCalendar} from 'react-big-calendar';
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using private repository or have proxy repository(to cache modules) between your system and npm repository, if yes then add following line in your .npmrc file and then try to check if it works :-

```
@types:registry = "https://registry.npmjs.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the package from npm:

```
npm install --save react-big-calendar
```